# Some animations makes the model lean forward. sometimes almost 90 degrees on the X axis

Tags: animation, rigging, rigify

I'm currently trying practicing animation and animating a very broken down model with separated parts like separate neck, head, fingers(except the feet) just to test out how to deal with that scenario. I just mentioned those because maybe it's necessary. So after I finished an animation, I cycle through them to look at the how I spaced out the keyframes most of the time. But sometimes, there's an animation that just messes up the whole model's rotation even when I made sure to put an initial keyframe for rotation and location for each movable part to prevent those scenarios. I nuked my animations multiple times already and it still happens for some reason, and it's quite annoying. I'll include the blend file so you guys inspect it. I guess you could already know which animation should not make the model rotate when you open the file. The "swordAction" animation rotates the model

I don't know how to include videos here, so here's a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UMxR5X89gBBjhCY_Jw71JS9B6NcWtSVb/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: I can't see the armature rotating like you say, it will rotate if you give it the swordAction action, because this action is supposed to make the sword rotate, if you give it to the armature it will make the armature itself rotate like any kind of object. Is it your problem here? Because I can't see any keyframe that would affect the armature object itself in the other actions...

Comment: I don't know if it's an armature problem. Even when the sword wasn't there on my previous animations, some animation would just rotate the whole rig/model on a weird, unexplanable(for me at least) way.

Comment: Could you please share a video of your problem with the whole interface? I can't see it rotate with the current settings, unless I give it the swordAction action

Comment: Ok, I'll try to record one. That was what I meant. swordAction somehow rotates the whole thing even when there were intial keyframes for the other animations for rotation and location to prevent that scenario

Comment: Added a google drive link for the video

Comment: The action called swordAction is supposed to rotate the object to which it is assigned, if you assign it to the armature object, it will rotate this object. If you put another action above it in the NLA it may cancel this rotation, depending on this second action and depending on the strip settings

Comment: Yes as I say it rotates as soon as you give it swordAction, swordAction is not attached to an object in particular, it will act on the object to which you'll assign it, if this action consists on a rotation, it will make the armature rotate. If you then choose another action, if this new action has no rotation information, the armature object won't rotate back to a default rotation, it will keep the rotation inherited from the previous action.

Comment: Also you need to note that there are 2 sorts of keyframes for an armature: the keyframe that you can give in Object mode to your armature object itself, and the keyframes that you can give in Pose mode to its bones.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that info about the types of keyframe. I looked at object mode and there was rotation applied to swordAction somehow. That would be very helpful in the future for troubleshooting. Thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your armature rotates as soon as you give it *swordAction*, *swordAction* is not attached to an object in particular, it will act on the object to which you'll assign it, if this action consists on a rotation, it will make the armature rotate. If you then choose another action, if this new action has no rotation information, the armature object won't rotate back to a default rotation, it will keep the rotation inherited from the previous action (here, *swordAction*).

Also you need to note that there are 2 sorts of keyframes for an armature: the keyframe that you can give in *Object* mode to your armature object itself, and the keyframes that you can give in *Pose* mode to its bones.

I guess it's generally not recommended to give an object action to an armature, if you want to rotate the whole armature, rather parent it to an empty that will have the rotation action.